# Socket IO Rooms: Trying to use rooms in a game app (react-native) so multiple groups of people can play the game independently of each other

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

I have an app where multiple people join a game by entering a code that is generated on the phone hosting the game. I want to use this code as the name of a socket io room, so multiple games can be going on between different groups of players.

Here is my server code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //passing in the game_code from client side and using it as the room name
    socket.on('names', function (game_code) {
        socket.join(game_code);
        io.to(game_code).emit('names')
    });
    socket.on('round_start', function (game_code) {
        io.to(game_code).emit('round_start')
    });
    socket.on('game_start', function (game_code) {
        io.to(game_code).emit('game_start')
    });
    socket.on('end_round', function (game_code) {
        io.to(game_code).emit('end_round')
    });
    socket.on('next_round', function (game_code) {
        io.to(game_code).emit('next_round')
    });
    socket.on('end_game', function (game_code) {
        io.to(game_code).emit('end_game')
    });
});
```

The 'names' socket is for players entering their name before the game starts, and the rest of them are for transitions to the next screen; one phone, usually the host, presses a button that causes all the phones to go to the next screen. The 'names' socket is working correctly, and so is the 'round_start' socket, which is the first screen transition. The next screen transition after this does not work.

All of the screen transitions work if I don't use rooms, so I'm pretty sure my react-native code isn't the problem here. It must be something wrong with the server code I've shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didnt provide full source, I can only assume what might went wrong.

First of all, since you used `io.to(game_code).emit('names')` I assume, you want the 'names' event to be sent to all clients in the room `game_code`, including the sender.

(Sidenote: If you want this event to be sent to all users in the room, except the sender, you should have used `socket.to(game_code).emit('names')`. See https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/ )

But, since the `.join` method is asynchronous, the 'names' event may gets fired, before the client joined the room. So the sender never receives the 'names' event fired by himself, only the 'names' events, fired by other clients.

To ensure, the 'names' event gets fired after the client joined the room, you can use a callback for the `.join` method:  `socket.join(room, callback)`.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //passing in the game_code from client side and using it as the room name
  socket.on('names', function (game_code) {
      socket.join(game_code, (game_code) => io.to(game_code).emit('names'););
  });
  //rest of your code
});
```

In case you're unfamiliar with the `=>` arrow function , `(game_code) => io.to(game_code).emit('names')` is short for

```
function (game_code){
  return io.to(game_code).emit('names');
}
```

(nevermind the return keyword, it's just part of the arrow function)